# Border on a Dynamic Size Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an `Image` inside a `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Stretch="Uniform" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Since the stretch is set to `Uniform`, it won't fill the grid completely. The image source is also changing continously, and each source might have a completely different width and height.

I want to put a `Border` around the image, how do I do that? If I simply put:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Width="{Binding ElementName="myImage", Path=RenderedSize.Width}" 
            Height="{Binding ElementName="myImage", Path=RenderedSize.Height}">
        <Image x:Name="myImage"
               ... />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

It will wrap the entire Grid instead of just the `Uniform` image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **`HorizontalAlignment`** and **`VerticalAlignment`** as **`Center`** on border.
Default value is **`Stretch`** so it stretches to fill the entire grid.

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Image x:Name="myImage"/>
</Border>
```